# bash - base64 decode problem invalid input in QNAP server

Tags: bash, ubuntu, base64, decode

I have a problem with command **base64** in bash on my **QNAP server**

when i typing command:

`echo QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | base64 --decode`

i get result with invalid input:

`Aladdin:open sesamebase64: invalid input`

i tested this input in **PHP** and also i tested in **ubuntu** bash end its all ok:

`Aladdin:open sesame`

why i have base64: invalid input?

Answer (score 0):

i add flag "--ignore-garbage" and its i thing ok

probably old version base64 (6.7)